# What is the best practice for addressing Table overflow when printing with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have an HTML table that is too wide for portrait layout when printing.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I'm wondering what the best practice is for breaking this table? Or possibly shrinking it? Or is there something else I haven't considered.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the data and your use case but tablesaw is a pretty cool plugin that is probably what you are looking for: https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

Comment: i had the same issue, and i was unable to find solution, however if you use datatable plugin it will do a the trick